# KendoUI Treeview Select Node On Databound

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a list view I want the user to be able to double click which will change a treeview's datasource and select a treeview node.  While I get the ID of the item I want to select, execute the code I think should select the node on the treeview, it does not select.  Any thoughts would be appreciated

Listview Double Click Event:

```
  function setItemDoubleClickEvent() {
     $(".machineInstances").on("dblclick", function () {
      var listView = $("#listView").data("kendoListView");
      var idx = $(this).index();
      var item = listView.dataSource.view()[idx];
      $('#selectedNodeId').val(item.InstanceId);

      // Remove the current datasource to remove any existing filtering
      $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").setDataSource([]);

      // Set the hidden input so OnData knows what to highlight
      $('#selectedNodeId').val(item.InstanceId);

      // Set the new datasource for the tree
      $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").setDataSource(instanceDataSource);              });
   }
```

TreeView Declaration:

```
             var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                    dataTextField: "Name"
                    , select: onSelect,
                    dataBound: ondata
                }).data("kendoTreeView"),
```

DataBound Function:

```
 function ondata() {
     //alert($('#selectedNodeId').val());
     var selected = $('#selectedNodeId').val();
      if (selected != "") {

          var node = treeview.findByUid(selected)
          $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").select(node);
          $('#selectedNodeId').val("");
       }
   }
```

Thank you,

Drew

Comment: Why do you say that `$("#menuInstances").click();` _ sets the datasource of the tree_? What is `menuInstances`? I don't see why I click on anything sets a `datasource`

Comment: Sorry, I can see why this would cause confusion.  I have updated my code above to include the databinding.  The issues is that the tree is not highlighting the selected node.

Comment: UID in the treeview are assigned by the system, correct? But seems that you get it from the list view as InstanceId. How do you fill `InstanceId` in listview for having the same `uid` that kendo assigns to your tree?

Comment: You are correct, that does not make sense.  I needed to add "var dataItem = treeview.dataSource.get(selected)" right before I find by uid and that did the trick.  Thank you for your help and making me think.